# Kibana Dashboard multiple time periods and search terms

Tags: kibana-4

Is it possible to give different time periods or different search terms to each Visualization in a Kibana Dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently - no.

This is on the list of enhancements that the 'elastic' team will implement soon, but doesn't have any due date yet.
You could follow the open issue here: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3578

Answer (score 0):

I think i've understood your question.
Lets supose this is yout data whitin elasticSearch:

```
timestamp  level   message
19:05:15   error   connection failed
19:06:30   debug   connection succesfull
```

You can reflect your percentajes of each level in differente time periods (10% of debug, 20% of errors, 14% of info and so on). For instance you can design a chart for the last 1 hour and other one for the last day in the same dashboard, so you don't need to manipulate the date picker in de header.

1. First you have to make a query to filter your data by the timestamp
   (ex. last day):

   @timestamp:[now-1d TO now]
2. Second, you need to save this search, and name it.
3. Finally, design whatever visualization you need based on this
   search, and the results will be bound to it.
4. Repeat with different time periods.

Hope this helps. Bye.